# I get a link error when i add a constructor to my derived class

Tags: c++

I get **'error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol'** when I comment in my `constructor` in my derived class.

My base class defines a virtual `OnEnter` and `OnExit`, my derived class implements those functions, all is good. Then when I add a constructor to my derived class it wont compile.

```
1>State.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall State::OnEnter(void)" (?OnEnter@State@@UAEXXZ)
1>State.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall State::OnExit(void)" (?OnExit@State@@UAEXXZ)
```

State is my base class.

```
//State.h
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H

class State
{
public:
    virtual void OnEnter();
    virtual void OnExit();
};

#endif

//State.cpp
#include "State.h"


//DateEntryView.h
#ifndef DATE_ENTRY_VIEW_H
#define DATE_ENTRY_VIEW_H

#include "State.h"

class DateEntryView
    : public State
{
public:
    DateEntryView();
public:
    void OnEnter();
    void OnExit();
};

#endif

//DateEntryView.cpp
#include "DateEntryView.h"

DateEntryView::DateEntryView()
{

}

void DateEntryView::OnEnter()
{

}

void DateEntryView::OnExit()
{

}
```

Comment: show some code, please

Comment: please insert the code, at the moment I can tell that there is error LNK2001

Comment: You made some mistake. More info impossible until you show us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Matt I added the code, this code is part of a bigger project, I commented out all the code and dependencies before asking the question on the forum

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 code added

Comment: @ArneMertz I added an SSCCE

Comment: lol it builds for ARM with gcc, its only the x86 build that fails wtf!

Comment: why do people keep down voting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided an implementation for OnEnter or OnExit in the source you have supplied.

If they are supposed to have implementations, then you presumably have a state.c file which, when you compile, produces a state.o file. When you produce your executable you need to include this file in the linking stage.

If they are not supposed to have implementations, eg. if it is an abstract base class, then you need to declare them like this:

```
virtual void OnEnter() = 0;
virtual void OnExit() = 0;
```

Comment: thanks, pure virtual is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your OnEnter and OnExit methods pure virtual in your state class.

like this

```
class State
{
public:
  virtual void OnEnter() = 0;
  virtual void OnLeave() = 0;
};

class StateOne : public virtual State
{

public:

  StateOne()
  {
  }

  virtual void OnEnter()
  {
  }

  virtual void OnLeave()
  {
  }

};


int main()
{
  State *state = new StateOne;
  state->OnEnter();
  state->OnLeave();
  delete state;

  return 0;
}
```

Or if you don't want them pure virtual add braces

```
class State
{
public:
  virtual void OnEnter()
  {
  }
  virtual void OnLeave()
  {
  }
};
```

Comment: if you implement them in the base class, you don't need do that.

Comment: Depends on the request abstract base class vs non abstract base class

Comment: i don't know why they down voted your post but i did want to make them pure virtual thanks

Comment: Its strange because it built with another compiler and worked for another set of derived classes. So weird. I think its because those objects were not being instantiated had code commented out etc.